# Santander investment platform

Tags: investing, fees, starting-out-investing, investment-strategies, fund-manager

Santander (the bank) offer an 'investment platform', where you can invest in various funds (albeit, a limited range) for a management fee.

Is this a reasonable provider to use? What are the pros and cons over an online  broker?

Answer (score 2):

If you look carefully, you'll see that the "bank side" of the company is not offering this function.

https://www.santanderbank.com/us/personal/investing-insurance/investment-services

> Securities and advisory services are offered through Santander Investment Services, a division of Santander Securities, LLC. Santander Securities, LLC is a registered broker/dealer, Member FINRA and SIPC and a registered investment advisor. Insurance is offered through Santander Securities, LLC or its affiliates.

Many banks have affiliated investment arms. I'd bet it's management fees are pretty high.

> What are the pros

Convenience of a single web site for banking and investing.

> and cons over an online broker?

(This **is** an online broker.)

Expense.  Low cost brokers and mutual fund firms like Vanguard, Fidelity and Schwab are definitely the way to go.

Comment: Could you provide reputable brokers to use from the UK / Europe if possible? Thanks for your help.